# SQL entities , multiple relationship

Tags: mysql, entity-relationship

[ER sketch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pR9mt.jpg)

is it possible to have this kind of relationship with 2 entities, was told that these will make data duplication problems
THANK YOU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, It is possible to create more than one relationship between two entities. For example `works for` and `managed by` are two relationships between the entities `Employee` and `Department`. `works for` relationship is used to represent the department that which he is working, and `managed by` relationship is used to represent the manager of a department. Note that manager is also an employee.

Comment: so here if i take the user and items the relationship could be use

User >0 --- Donates   ----- |< Item  and
User >0 --- Requests ----- |< Item

>0 = many - zero
|<= one-many

is this also correct
THANK YOU

Comment: Yes, you are correct. And if my answer is useful to you please accept and upvote it. Thank you